# Crash when assigning to std::future under MSVC's Debug mode

Tags: c++, visual-c++, future

The following code crashes in random intervals when built with MSVC under `Debug` mode, unlike the `Release`.

```
#include <future>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    auto l = [](){};
    auto f = async(launch::async, l);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
        f = async(launch::async, l);
}
```

The console output says:

> f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\stdcpp\thr\mutex.c(51): mutex destroyed while
>   busy

The full call stack is: https://pastebin.com/0g2ZF5C1

Now obviously it's just a stress test, but am I doing something utterly stupid? It seems to me it's fine to reassign a new task to an existing future, as it's said that `operator=`:

> Releases any shared state and move-assigns the contents of other to
>   *this

(Due to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/operator%3D).

Is it a bug in MSVC's runtime?

Remarkably, the program stops crashing if I manually call wait() before the assignment, thus making the loop into:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
    f.wait();
    f = async(launch::async, l);
}
```

Isn't `operator=` itself supposed to call `wait`?

Background:

`_MSC_VER` equals `1911`

Code was built with help of:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 Preview(2)
Version 15.4.0 Preview 2.0
```

Just opened a brand new C++ project.

Comment: Exact version of msvc and compiler would be useful.

Comment: Just a guess: Sometimes probably 'l' is still executed while you try to reassign f. Probably the overhead of creating the lambda in debug is much bigger compared to the overhead of the debug version of the remaining code. That could explain that it only happens in the debug version.

Comment: @Yakk Sure, I've edited the question.

Comment: @JoergS It's a plausible explanation, but I can't get Release to crash even if the lambda sleeps for a random duration of time.

Comment: That lambda is only ever assigned to once.  It's used a lot, and even COPIED, but `l` itself is only ever assigned to once.

Comment: Does it happen in a non-preview version of Visual Studio 2017? Like 15.3.4

Comment: @RustyX Same result.

Comment: _Isn't operator= itself supposed to call wait?_ what makes you think so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't `operator=` itself supposed to call `wait`?

I don't know whether it is *supposed* to, but a cursory glance at the MSVC15.3.4 implementation of `<future>` seems to strongly suggest it doesn't.

```
//User Code
future f = /*...*/;
f = /*...*/; //(1)
```

> ```
> //MSVC Code
> future& operator=(future&& _Right) _NOEXCEPT //(1)
>     {   // assign from rvalue future object
>     _Mybase::operator=(_STD move(_Right)); //(2)
>     return (*this);
>     }
> _State_manager& operator=(_State_manager&& _Other) //(2)
>     {   // assign from rvalue _Other
>     _Move_from(_Other); //(3)
>     return (*this);
>     }
> void _Move_from(_State_manager& _Other) //(3)
>     {   // move stored associated asynchronous state object from _Other
>     if (this != _STD addressof(_Other))
>         {   // different, move
>         if (_Assoc_state)
>             _Assoc_state->_Release(); //(4)
>         _Assoc_state = _Other._Assoc_state;
>         _Other._Assoc_state = 0;
>         _Get_only_once = _Other._Get_only_once;
>         }
>     }
> void _Release() //(4)
>     {   // decrement reference count and destroy when zero
>     if (_MT_DECR(_Refs) == 0)
>         _Delete_this(); //(5)
>     }
> void _Delete_this() //(5)
>     {   // delete this object
>     if (_Deleter)
>         _Deleter->_Delete(this); //External Code
>     else
>         delete this;
>     }
> ```

Seeing as calling `wait` helps synchronize things and ensure that the `future` object is in a safe state to be modified, it might be better to include the `wait` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I got to this question since I had a very similar issue with MSVC debug mode, getting sporadic crashes with the `mutex destroyed while busy` message.

In my case it turns out that it was an issue with VS2017 that had been present up until version 15.8 (as specified [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/257344/stdasync-can-crash-or-deadlock.html)).

Updating to VS2019 solved this issue for me. Although this question is pretty old, I'm writing this up as another alternative answer.